# Success callback after subscription values arrive

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to do something after the values of a subscription arrive but the success callback is never called.

```
this.items = this.af.database.object( 'items' , {preserveSnapshot:true} );
this.itemsSub = this.items.subscribe(
  snapshot =>{ this.values = snapshot.val(); },
  (err) => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('this.values')
);
```

Also, I've been suggested to change it to `this.items.take(1).subscribe` but doing so, the log for this.values returns undefined.

Comment: How exactly do you know the success callback is never called? There doesn't seem to be anything overtly wrong about the code you included. Where and how are you implementing `this.values`? You may be trying to access it before AngularFire has had a chance to do its thing.

Comment: What's the output for `snapshot =>{ this.values = snapshot.val(); console.log(this.values); },`?

Comment: @AndrewBabin The log doesn't appear in the console with the first code. If you add the take(1) method it works, but values are undefined. And yes, I know the problem is that the values are being accessed before they are available. That's why I thought the success callback would wait for the values to come before running the function. Obviously I'm wrong. The question here is how can I do that. Right now I'm relying on a timeout function but that's a really ugly way to solve it.

Comment: Nevermind... The problem was that I was trying to access the values from outside the snapshot function. If I put the function inside it waits for the values to arrive. Thanks anyway!